# Getting error on using MKReverseGeoCoder

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkreversegeocoder

When we are trying to use MKReverseGeoCoder always getting an error,

"/SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-47.1/Runtime/PBRequester.m:682 server returned error: 503

error : Error Domain=PBRequesterErrorDomain Code=6001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PBRequesterErrorDomain error 6001.)"".

On searching for details, we found that the error is due to increased rate of reverse geocoding requests. But we are sending only one request at a time and sure that the request count is less. Please explain the details behind the error. We used CLGeoCoder and it works fine. Please suggest a way to solve the problem in versions older than IOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is happening because you are in testing, and using the reverse geocoder too much and Google's servers know that. So, it has basically blocked you for a while. Try again later and see if it works.

You need to make sure that you are not calling the geocoder more than once every 60 seconds.